# Why isn't this plotting multiple functions in one graph?

Tags: r, plot, reliability

I'm having some problems trying to plot multiple reliability functions in one single graph from a inverse gaussian distirbution. I need the functions to be lines, and all I got is points, when trying to set type="l", it happens to be a mess drawing mulitle lines everywhere.

Here is the code

```
library("statmod")
x<-rinvgauss(90,0.000471176,0.0000191925)
y<-rinvgauss(90,0.000732085,0.000002982015)
z<-rinvgauss(180,0.000286672,0.00000116771)

den<-pinvgauss(x,0.000471176,0.0000191925)
dens<-pinvgauss(y,0.000732085,0.000002982015)
densi<-pinvgauss(z,0.000286672,0.00000116771)

rel<-1-den
reli<-1-dens
relia<-1-densi

plot(x,rel, xlim=c(0,0.002), col="red")
points(y,reli, col="blue")
points(z,relia, col="black")
```

I would really appreciate any help on this!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community! You should accept Ron's answer so he can get the points for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your x, y, z values aren't sorted...

```
library("statmod")
x <- sort(rinvgauss(90,0.000471176,0.0000191925))
y <- sort(rinvgauss(90,0.000732085,0.000002982015))
z <- sort(rinvgauss(180,0.000286672,0.00000116771))

den   <- pinvgauss(x,0.000471176,0.0000191925)
dens  <- pinvgauss(y,0.000732085,0.000002982015)
densi <- pinvgauss(z,0.000286672,0.00000116771)

rel   <- 1-den
reli  <- 1-dens
relia <- 1-densi

plot(x,rel, xlim=c(0,0.002), col="red", type="l")
lines(y,reli, col="blue")
lines(z,relia, col="black")
```

Comment: Thanks a lo!! That is it! That was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your values weren't sorted. This should work:

```
    x<-sort(rinvgauss(90,0.000471176,0.0000191925))
    y<-sort(rinvgauss(90,0.000732085,0.000002982015))
    z<-sort(rinvgauss(180,0.000286672,0.00000116771))

den<-sort(pinvgauss(x,0.000471176,0.0000191925))
dens<-sort(pinvgauss(y,0.000732085,0.000002982015))
densi<-sort(pinvgauss(z,0.000286672,0.00000116771))

rel<-1-den
reli<-1-dens
relia<-1-densi

plot(x,rel, xlim=c(0,0.002), col="red",type="l")
lines(y,reli, col="blue")
lines(z,relia, col="black")
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!

Comment: Ha I just saw someone already answered the same thing ^^ You should pick the previous answer :)